# How to generate graphs from .heap files created by google HEAPPROFILER

Tags: c++, google-perftools

Like the question says I created some .heap files using awesome google perftools and now I cant view them(ofc i can open them in the vim, but I want graphical representation )...
I tried using the (like in the documentation)

pprof --gv name-of-my-program /my_heap_file.0100.heap

```
 but I get
```

pprof: invalid option -- '-' pprof: invalid option -- 'g'

---

Comment: You need google-pprof not the tau package! See this thread stackoverflow.com/a/7758044/1029144 .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `pprof` is provided by installing `tau`.

Use the absolute path to `(perftools)pprof` to use it, something like `/usr/local/bin/pprof`

Comment: i have it in /usr/bin/pprof , but fullpath changes nothing                  /usr/bin/pprof: invalid option -- '-'
/usr/bin/pprof: invalid option -- 'g'
usage: /usr/bin/pprof [-c|-b|-m|-t|-e|-i|-v] [-r] [-s] [-n num] [-f filename] [-p] [-l] [-d] [node numbers]

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Perhaps, some other package is installing an binary with same name.

Comment: ah, stupid me, downloaded tar and it contained pprof inside, now everything works. Sorry for dumb question. :)

Comment: How is this the answer? tau is not the package you want.

Comment: The pprof tool from tau is not the tool that you should use.

Answer (score 3):

There are two tools called pprof. One comes with part of the tau package and it is installed on many machines. However it knows nothing about Google Perf Tools and it should not be used.

The other pprof tool comes with Google Perf Tools. This is the version that you should run. The documentation should be updated to make this more obvious.

Comment: Sometimes, e.g. in ubuntu and possibly in debian, the right perl script `pprof` from gperftools (ex google-perftools, code.google.com/p/gperftools/) is called `google-pprof`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/google-pprof.1.html